# GWT How to open a windows explorer and show the contents of the folder in order to make then downloadable

Tags: gwt, servlets, jboss, download

Using GWT, I would like to open a window showing the content of the folder in my hard disk, and then, select one file and download it. Let's say it's the opposite  of the file upload,
I tried `Window.open("E:\\outil pfe bfi\\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\\standalone\\deployments\\uploaded", "_blank", null);`
 but it only open a blank window. In the server side, I created a servlet to ensure downloading files :

```
public class DownloadDiskImpl extends HttpServlet {
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.doGet(req, resp);
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String fileName = (String) req.getSession().getAttribute("fileName");


    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();

    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int length;
    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
        out.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    in.close();
    out.flush();

}
```

}

and then, I don't know how to do next. Is there a possibility to do that?
NB: I forget to mention that the path: `E:\\outil pfe bfi\\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\\standalone\\deployments\\uploaded` is a folder under the server location where I uploaded some files, and I want to download them by a clik on a button

Comment: First of all, your E:\\outil pfe bfi\\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\\standalone\\deployments\\uploaded is surely not an URL you can access from your client normally. And then, if you want to download your file using your servlet, you're supposed to give the right URL for your resource so you have to serve a hand-made files list to your client. And then i'm pretty sure that if you try to post your request using doPost to your DownloadDiskImpl servlet, you'll never get your doGet method called as doPost calls a super.doGet which is the one from HttpServlet (or upper in hierarchy). Review your basis :)

Comment: So, how can I proceed step by step? how can I open the window ?

Comment: 1st : create a service (Servlet or whatsoever) that returns your files with the right URL associated to each.

Comment: 2cd : use your download servlet.